# Sniffing HTTPS traffic from client program

Tags: c++, security, http, https

this might be a dumb question...

I wrote a C++ client program that communicates with a web service over HTTPS with the help of the cURL library.

I am wondering if the person using the client can see clearly the traffic originating from his computer using some sniffing program?

Or would he see encrypted data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a utility like `netcat` to sniff data on the wire, the user would only see encrypted data. The only way to see the raw data is to log it inside the app, before it's passed to cURL, OR to find it in the machine's active RAM (much more difficult since it's likely to be fragmented).

Answer (score 2):

Not if your app checks for valid certificates.

If your users have the ability to use a proxy server with your app, they could use fiddler's decrypt https sessions function to do this, but it results in an invalid certificate which could be made to stop it from working when detected.

Comment: I am kind of new to security and such...my web service is a Google App Engine app, would you have any pointers on how to "check for valid certificate" ? Thanks for your time!

Comment: cURL (at least using from the command line) automatically checks to ensure the certificate is issued by a trusted Certificate Authority (CA).

Comment: okay so by default, I would be checking for valid certificate without me even knowing? Cool :)

Comment: I'd verify with the library docs just to make sure, but the command-line cURL does. :)

Answer (score 1):

He would see the encrypted data. Sniffers only see the packets, so if HTTPS is working as it should, the packets should be encrypted, and that's all the program could see.

If you would like to try it yourself, learn about ettercap-ng.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that an average user would be able to do that...

BUT there are ways to do this like:

- replacing the cURL library with a proxy (if you link dynamically)
- running your program under a debugger and placing breakpoints on the cURL functions
- replacing the cURL program with a proxy (if you use it as a commandline utility)
- digging deep and diessecting the memory at runtime

From my POV it is improbable (since you need some skill + knowledge + some control over the client environment to pull that off) but possible...

Comment: Thanks, if a user manages to do that, he deserves to see the data lol :p It's not THAT critical so detering the average user is quite enough.

Comment: @ibiza glad to read that :-) defensive measures can be really messy if they were needed...

Answer (score 0):

The SSL/TLS protocol is typically implemented at the application layer, so the data is encrypted before it is sent.

Comment: TLS stands for transport layer security,  not application layer.

Comment: @Rook - you're right about the acronym, but not your conclusion.

Comment: the conclusion is that someone on the machine will always be able to sniff the traffic.  Period end of story.

Comment: @Rook - the wikipedia page on TLS should address your confusion as to where the TLS sits in the protocol stack. Clearly, it's not in the *transport layer*.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has access to the certificate key(s) used to encrypt/decrypt the data, then he/she can plug them into WireShark and it can then decode sniffed HTTPS packets off the wire.